# csvsimple vs. conditional row coloring

Tags: conditionals, csv, csvsimple, rowcolor

I've a CSV file what I want process with [csvsimple](https://ctan.org/pkg/csvsimple). My desire is to color some rows based on a conditional (one specified column has bigger value). Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,1,2,2
1,3,2,1
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
  \csvreader[
    head to column names,
    before line={\ifnum\d>1\rowcolor{gray}\fi},
    late after line={\\}
  ]{mwe.csv}{}{
    \a&\b&\c&\d
  }
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

In this case I gave an error message:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.  
<recently read> \noalign                             
l.18   }
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your error stems from `\rowcolor`not being at the very beginning of the row. You can fix that by adding an additional `\\` at the beginning of a row. It would also be better to use a filter (section 3.4 of the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf)) to process conditionals:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,1,2,2
1,3,2,1
3,4,5,0
6,7,8,1
8,6,4,2
9,1,2,4
0,0,1,1
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}
\csvreader[head to column names,
           full filter=\ifnumgreater{\d}{1}
                       {\\\rowcolor{gray} \csvfilteraccept}
                       {\\                \csvfilteraccept}
           ]{\jobname.csv}{}{\csvlinetotablerow}%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't work well if you've a third line in CSV ("1,1,2,2") or the second line matches too.

Comment: @uzsolt fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution. It adds a line break after each row.

```
 
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents*}{mwe.csv}
a,b,c,d
1,1,2,2
5,3,9,1
7,8,2,9
5,3,9,1
5,3,9,1
7,8,2,9
\end{filecontents*}

  \csvreader[tabular=cccc,
    head to column names,
    before line={\ifnum\d>1\\\rowcolor{gray}\else\\\fi}
  ]{mwe.csv}{}{
    \a&\b&\c&\d
  }


\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't **\else\\** then you will have this result:

[image]

Comment: There are empty lines. Compare it *without* the `before line={\ifnum\d>1\\\rowcolor{gray}\else\\\fi}` option!

Comment: I want equal height :)

Comment: @Compiii Your solution works great, if you omit the option `tabular=cccc,` (it adds an additional line break at the end) and put the whole `\csvreader`-statement inside of the tabular-environment.