# Highlight maximum value in each row in csvsimple table

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I am currently using `csvsimple` (in pdfLaTeX) to generate a table from a csv file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\def\myasdf{1.5cm}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=4}
  \centering
  \csvreader[tabular=l|p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf},
            table head=\toprule Test Sequence & A & B & C & D & E & F\\ \midrule,
            head to column names,
            late after last line=\\\bottomrule]
            {csvs/data.csv}%
            {liu2021_vimeo90k_weighted_ex5a-v1_325000=\liuexFivea,
            liu2021_vimeo90k_weighted_ex1a-v1_825000=\liuexOnea,
            drdbnet_vimeo90k_weighted_ex16a-v1_375000=\drdbSixteena,
            drdbnet_vimeo90k_weighted_ex12b-v3_682917=\drdbTwelveb}%
            {\csvcoli & \num{\liuexFivea} & \num{\liuexOnea} &%
             \num{\drdbSixteena} & \num{\drdbTwelveb} & \num{\yadif} & \num{\zhu}
            }\\
  \caption{Example Caption}
  \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

How can I adapt this code to highlight in each row the maximum value(s)? I don't care if it's by making the text bold, changing the cell background color, or any other way.

---

So far I found

- [how to color the whole row (csvsimple)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468208/csvsimple-vs-conditional-row-coloring)
- how to do it with a [completely different approach (datatools)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447330/102826) that would require me to figure out all the other details again
- [how to do it with pgfplotstable](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/551079/highlighting-maximum-value-in-pgfplotstable-works-partially)
- [how to find the minimum (pgfplotstable)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33967/highlighting-extremal-values-in-table)

I would prefer not having to learn how to use a new package though, since my table already looks how I want it to and I know how to adapt the table I have for similar uses. Is there a way to do this highlighting with csvsimple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple csv file `610711.csv`:

```
ooo,aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd,eee,fff
ooa,0.32,0.22,0.99,0.35,1.22,0.19
oob,1.22,1.72,3.27,2.05,3.21,3.27
ooc,4.10,0.32,2.49,1.10,0.52,2.19
```

A solution with `expl3` code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand { \getmax } { }
  {
    \clist_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_clist {\aaa, \bbb, \ccc, \ddd, \eee, \fff}
    \clist_sort:Nn \g_tmpa_clist
      {
        \fp_compare:nNnTF {##1} < {##2}
          { \sort_return_swapped: }
          { \sort_return_same: }
      }
    \tl_gset:Nx \g_tmpa_tl { \clist_item:Nn \g_tmpa_clist {1} }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \mynum } { m }
  {
    \fp_compare:nNnTF { #1 } = { \g_tmpa_tl }
      { \cellcolor{blue!20} \num{#1} }
      { \num{#1} }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\def\myasdf{1.5cm}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \sisetup{round-mode=places, round-precision=4}
  \centering
  \csvreader[tabular=lp{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf}p{\myasdf},
            table head=\toprule Test Sequence & A & B & C & D & E & F\\ \midrule,
            head to column names,
            before line=\getmax,
            late after last line=\\\bottomrule]
            {610711.csv}%
            {}%
            {\csvcoli & \mynum{\aaa} & \mynum{\bbb} &%
             \mynum{\ccc} & \mynum{\ddd} & \mynum{\eee} & \mynum{\fff}
            }
  \caption{Example Caption}
  \label{tab:table1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This looks perfect! I even think I understand what is happening there, thank you! I figure if I will grasp the details the best way is to look at the expl3 manual? If I want to use this in multiple tables, do I have to redefine the commands since they make use of global variables or is it ok to reuse, perhaps by resetting `g_tmpa_tl` somehow? (I will probably only get around to using it tomorrow. I'll give the checkmark out then :) )

Comment: The manual of expl3 is `interface3.pdf`. It is OK to reuse `g_tmpa_tl` since it is a scratch global variable.

Comment: So, this works exactly as promised when I use the example you're providing. When I add an alias `aaa=\asdf`, and use `\asdf`  instead of `\aaa` it still works, so aliases seem to be supported. However when I use it with my alias `drdbnet_vimeo90k_weighted_ex12b-v3_682917=\asdf`, and change the example csv header from `aaa` to this long name, compilation fails with `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \aaa` although there is nowhere an explicit `\aaa`  in use. Would you know what's going on? Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Okay nevermind, somehow the problem is not my long name with underscores... even `ab`  instead of `aaa`  as header fails. I did not realize they were hardcoded in the command. My bad.

Comment: You can also try to use \csvcolii, \csvcoliii, \csvcoliv, \csvcolv instead of \aaa, \bbb, \ccc, \ddd.

Comment: I'm not using all the columns from my file, and having the aliases is nice for being sure I'm getting the right numbers. I've added the aliased commands to the expl instead of `\aaa` etc and that is working well. Just means I will likely have to redefine the command for every table, but that is ok